# how to Find Index in VMTHook

Tags: c++

How to find index in VMTHook? im sorry im just starting learning about another hooking method i already know about HWBP Hook,Detours,etc but this VMThook make me confused i cant find any forum that can help me 
this is the _asm that i want to hook http://prntscr.com/siz04i and this is my main function

```css
float Delay = 0;

_declspec (naked) void MainFunction()
{
 _asm
 {
  movss xmm0, Delay
  movss[esi + 0x58], xmm0
  jmp HookFunctionCall
 }
}
```

And this is the VMTHook Function that i want to use

```css
void* HookVTableFunction(void* pVTable, void* fnHookFunc, int nOffset) 
{
 intptr_t ptrVtable = *((intptr_t*)pVTable); // Pointer to our chosen vtable
 intptr_t ptrFunction = ptrVtable + sizeof(intptr_t) * nOffset; // The offset to the function (remember it's a zero indexed array with a size of four bytes)
 intptr_t ptrOriginal = *((intptr_t*)ptrFunction); // Save original address

 // Edit the memory protection so we can modify it
 MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
 VirtualQuery((LPCVOID)ptrFunction, &mbi, sizeof(mbi));
 VirtualProtect(mbi.BaseAddress, mbi.RegionSize, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &mbi.Protect);

 // Overwrite the old function with our new one
 *((intptr_t*)ptrFunction) = (intptr_t)fnHookFunc;

 // Restore the protection
 VirtualProtect(mbi.BaseAddress, mbi.RegionSize, mbi.Protect, &mbi.Protect);

 // Return the original function address incase we want to call it
 return (void*)ptrOriginal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the index of a vtable function you subtract the address of the vtable function pointer from the address of the vtable, if it's x86 you then divide this number by 4, if it's x64 you divide by 8.

You can find the address of the vtable easily, a pointer to it exists at offset 0x0 of every object of that class.

vTables only exist if the class has virtual functions.